# Pass variables set from vsvarsall.bat into shell script?

Tags: azure-pipelines

I need a way to pass all the environment variables set from running the vsvarsall.bat batch file from Visual Studio into my shell script. I currently have it setup as two different tasks in Visual Studio Team Service. So I run the batch file and check the box to keep changes to the environment, then run the shell script. But it doesn't seem like it keeps the changes doing `echo $LIB` returns nothing.

Comment: Do you mean run vsvarsall.bat by your shell script and change variables by vsvarsall.bat? What's the contents of the shell script and vsvarsall.bat for now. And a task in a environment can only works for the current environment not all environments. And if your build agent is installed on windows OS, you can also try powershell script.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the [VSTS Task Logging Command](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md) to set the variables in the first task so that the changed variables are available in the second task.

```
##vso[task.setvariable]value
```

> Sets a variable in the variable service of taskcontext. The first task
>   can set a variable, and following tasks are able to use the variable.
>   The variable is exposed to the following tasks as an environment
>   variable. When issecret is set to true, the value of the variable will
>   be saved as secret and masked out from log. Secret variables are not
>   passed into tasks as environment variables and must be passed as
>   inputs. Examples:
>
> `##vso[task.setvariable variable=testvar;]testvalue`
>
> `##vso[task.setvariable variable=testvar;issecret=true;]testvalue`